# Anyone have any ideas on how to make a photo realistic chipped paint concrete texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I've been racking my brain trying to make this chipped paint concrete texture.  I decided to make an account and see if anyone here may know the answer.  I'm looking to recreate the texture below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! [image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file of what you have to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.  Also this may help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PansYUHh-yo or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXR9BqkO9Nw or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWZFzAwFyQc or https://youtu.be/F7Pt-SOnJ5U?feature=shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@moonboots Thanks for the help!  I messed with it a bit more and found something I am happy with.  I included my node tree and an output image.

[image: Node Tree]

[image: Redner]

Comment: Care to share that texture? For some reason, i cannot create this, my nodes refuse to be inverted.

Comment: @Jaco Sure, I've never shared a material before.  Here is a blend file with the material included.  Hope that works! 

PS totally new to posting on this site.  Not sure how to upload a blend file on here. 

Here is a link to the blend file.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/22s9eocrey4vrt73q0f03/Chipped-Concrete.blend?rlkey=pebnkds5f0uv3xyddp39ij5xz&dl=0

Comment: That is just perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could try it this way: For the base color of your *Principlad BSDF* mix 2 *Noise Texture* nodes with different scales into a *Color > Mix Color* (in *Multiply* mode), and plug a *Noise Texture* into a *Bump* node that you plug into the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]